# div height 100% with header and footer - no tricks

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, height

I am trying to create a layout where I have a header (nav) of fixed height in px, a footer of fixed px as well and a div in between them that occupies the remaining space.

Broken Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/murid/0vcyqm3y/

What I'm trying to achieve is for that blue div to go all the way down to the footer. Keeping in mind that I'm using a "push" div to get the footer to sit at the bottom of the page in case the content of the page is short and that said content can be very long as well therefore pushing the footer down.

I've checked out similar questions on Stackoverflow but answers involve position absolute, JavaScript, or background color on the body, I'm trying to avoid all of these and have a simple CSS only solution with background color on the content div.

I'm using `Bootstrap` btw.

CSS and HTML:

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #wrap {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin-bottom: -50px;
    }
    
    nav.navbar {
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    section {
     padding: 10px 0;
     margin-left: -15px;
     margin-right: -15px;
    }
    
    .section-primary {
     background: #337ab7;
    }
    
    section > .row {
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    footer,
    .push {
     height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrap">
    
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Logo</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li>
          <a href="">Logout</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
    
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <section class="section-md section-primary">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
             Panel Body
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </section>
     </div>
    
     <div class="push"></div>
    
    </div>
    
    <footer>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Copyright</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li>
          <a href="">Logout</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say I'm not a fan of this.. but this is the only CSS solution I know..

http://codepen.io/pacMakaveli/pen/EjWXNw?editors=110

Otherwise, for a cleaner way, use flexbox.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
 height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#wrap > nav,
footer {
  display: table-row;
}

nav.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

section {
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
}

.section-primary {
 background: #337ab7;
}

.content {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

section > .row {
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <section class="section-md section-primary">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel Body
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Copyright</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work – blue div is still not taking full height. I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite, Chrome 42.

Comment: You have to apply the background-color on `.content` instead of `.container-fluid` .. see : http://codepen.io/pacMakaveli/pen/EjWXNw?editors=110 ..

Comment: Otherwise, you'll have to apply the same 'scheme' to you container : table > table-row > table-cell etc.. like I said, not a fan. You should use flex layout, it's much better for your case.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, that works. I've made yet another version with less elements, "section" becomes unnecessary as it gets replaced by ".content" http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvpEMd?editors=110

Comment: I now have a responsive table inside a panel, which is causing the entire layout to expand beyond 100% width - would you know how to solve it? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdWrKX?editors=110

Comment: That's what happens when you give it a fixed width in px, when your layout is created using percents. You have to let the table to take the full width of the parent, otherwise, that is the expected result of your table being scrollable once you give it a fixed width larger than the parent container.